# Can't get the Cordova cordova-plugin-geofence Plugin to work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to get the Cordova cordova-plugin-geofence Plugin to work. My testing device is a Google Nexus 5 (Android). I followed the steps from the documentation (https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence). It also said I needed Google Play Services on my device. I have that (8.1.15).

I

- installed the plugin into a clean PhoneGap project.
- initialized the plugin after the deviceready event.
- added a geofence and started listening for geofence transitions.
- walked in and out the geofence, but nothing happened.

Maybe I am forgetting something, but if I do please tell me. The only file I edited was index.js. And from that file I edited onDeviceReady and receivedEvent:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    window.geofence.initialize(function() {
        alert('success');
    }, function(err) {
        alert(err);
    });
},    
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    //add geofence
    window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
        id: 'abc', 
        latitude: 51.808944, 
        longitude: 4.667041, 
        radius: 3, 
        transitionType: 3, 
        notification: { 
            id: 1, 
            title: 'Welcome', 
            text: 'Hello', 
            smallIcon: 'file://img/icon.png', 
            icon: 'file://img/logo.png',
            openAppOnClick: false, 
            vibration: [2000], 
            data: {
                name: 'foo',
                lastName: 'bar'
            }
        }
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('Geofence successfully added');
        alert('Geofence successfully added');
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
        alert('Adding geofence failed: ' + reason);
    });

    //listen for geofences
    window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function(geofences) {
        geofences.forEach(function(geo) {
            console.log('Geofence transition detected', geo);
            alert('Geofence transition detected: ' + geo);
        });
    };
}
```

I received the two alerts (success and Geofence successfully added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with example application https://github.com/cowbell/ionic-geofence

Also this plugin uses Google Geofence API https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html and it is not accurate to the level of few meters. Try increase the radius, 3 meters is not enough to catch any transition, try with 100 instead.

For testing I am using [Lockito Fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=pl), in order to make it work you need to allow location mocking on your device.

Comment: I increased the radius to 30 meters. Then I walked away from the radius and back in it, but I got no notifications. I also used Mock Locations. After that I tried your example application. I got the white screen of death. When further investigating why I got the white screen of death I saw that I was missing the module Toaster. Console errors: https://gyazo.com/b843825c2505e3d2a60db3058715e34b

Comment: I see angular-toster is missing. Did you run `bower install` and `npm install` before starting application?

Comment: There are also few caveats you should take into account. First you won't get any javascript code callback if your app is not running in foreground on Android (but you should get local notification if notification object in geofence is set up). Second 30 meters still could be too small radius, this plugin just uses google api but not tweek it at all.

Comment: Yes I did run `bower install` and `npm install`. Now about the caveats. I had my app open in the background while using Mock Locations and didn't get any notifications so I guess the notification object isn't created? I also noticed that there doesn't pop up a [location icon](https://gyazo.com/9114080782d666e6b0ba97edc404cd40) at the status bar of my mobile phone when using my app. Besides that I looked at the [recent location requests](https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2014/12/AndroidLocationSettings-Location-Menu.jpg) in my phone settings, but didn't see my app in it.

Comment: I also tried 100 meters. Unfortunately this didn't work just like the 30 meter. I hope you can give more advice.

Comment: The example app is working now. I made a mistake when running `bower install`. [The console asked me to choose a version for angular](https://gyazo.com/4b780d6ba24ceab54da0540ae2d6aa31), but I had chosen the wrong number before. It might be handy to tell people in the documentation which number they need to enter. Anyway the example app gives me notifications. I still don't know why my app doesn't work, but at least I know the plugin works now.

Comment: My app works now. It did work at 100 meters now for some reason. I tried to figure out why it worked all the sudden, but without any luck.

Comment: Hi @tsubik, I am using the same plugin in ionic2. I am getting notification if the set location is my current location. But if i set geofence to some other location, i am not receiving the notification. I am using lockito for mocking location. Am i missing anything? My minimum radius is 500m. Please help

Comment: @AishApp Did you find the solution ?